# How to push response from axios.all to a vue data element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am using axios.all to do asynchronous calls to the YouTube API.

My code is:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      cats: [],
      dogs: [],
      catsAndDogs: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    search: function (){
      var that = this
      axios.all([
        axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=cats&key=API_KEY'),
        axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=dogs&key=API_KEY')
      ])
      .then(axios.spread(function (catsRes, dogsRes) {
        that.cats = catsRes
        that.dogs = dogsRes

        console.log(catsRes)
        console.log(dogsRes)
      }))
    }
  }
}
```

This is as far as I can get because when I try to put the response from axios.spread (catsRes or dogsRes) into the arrays, they end up empty.

However if I comment out 'that.cats = catsRes' and 'that.dogs = dogsRes' the console prints out the response fine.

Can someone tell me why this is not working?

Ideally I would like to have an array for just the cat videos, an array for the dog videos and an array with both cats and dogs.

*** EDIT ***

Top is the console response when I try to put the GET request data into the data element and bottom is the console response when I don't try to put the GET request data into the data element:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIndb.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axios response is an object with some additional information about the response. To get the actual response JSON data, use the response object's `data` property. Furthermore, it seems like the YouTube response puts the actual results in an `items` property, so use that too:

```js
async search () {
    const [cats, dogs] = await axios.all([
        axios.get('...cats url...'),
        axios.get('...dogs url...'),
    ]);

    this.cats = cats.data.items;
    this.dogs = dogs.data.items;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work... as soon as I try to put the response into the data element, this happens:

https://imgur.com/a/NY1nc

Top is console response when I try to put the response into the data element and the bottom is the console response from the second GET request and don't put it into a data element.

Comment: Everything becomes empty, which is the problem:
https://imgur.com/FfYp82b

Comment: @Dachan - It's not empty. That's what Vue's reactive objects look like. The easiest way to inspect the data is using Vue's amazing devtools. But if you really want to log it, you should first convert it to JSON and back: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.cats)))`